# How can i do this in perl, shortcut truthtable

Tags: perl, truthtable

I have simplified a truth table of a boolean function to the following:

```
A       B       C1      C2      Z
--------------------------------- 
0       0       0       0       1
0       0       0       1       1
0       0       1       0       1
0       0       1       1       1
0       1       0       0       1
0       1       0       1       1
0       1       1       0       1
0       1       1       1       1
1       0       0       0       1
1       0       0       1       1
1       0       1       0       1
1       0       1       1       1
1       1       0       0       1
1       1       0       1       0
1       1       1       0       0
1       1       1       1       0
```

The truth table after being trimmed :

```
A       B      C1      C2       Z
---------------------------------
0       0       0       x       0
x       x       x       0       0
1       x       x       1       1
x       1       x       1       1
x       x       1       1       1
```

I don't know how to trim the truth table creating `x` instead of `1` or `0`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so before posting your next question here.

Comment: Well...if ( 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 ) -> 1 and ( 1,0,0,0,0 ) -> 1 then ( 1,0,0,0,x ) -> 1....and similarly for other combinations.  You could just iterate through them and figure keep track of which variables are redundant...

Comment: @xxfelixxx  well  thank for your rep ! ^^ , can you tell me about n input

Answer (score 1):

Translating the matrix into code is quite simple.

```
sub Z {
   my ($C2, $C1, $B2, $B1, $A) = @_;
   return 1 if $C2 && $C1;
   return 1 if $B2 && $B1;
   return 1 if $A;
   return 0 if !$C2 && !$B1 && !$A;
   return 0 if !$C1 && !$B1 && !$A;
   return 0 if !$C2 && !$B2 && !$A;
   return 0 if !$C1 && !$B2 && !$A;
   croak("Should never be reached");
}
```

Since all possible inputs will result in one of the returns being executed, the above simplifies to the following:

```
sub Z {
   my ($C2, $C1, $B2, $B1, $A) = @_;
   return 1 if $C2 && $C1;
   return 1 if $B2 && $B1;
   return 1 if $A;
   return 0;
}
```

We can easily write that as one line.

```
my $Z = $C2 && $C1 || $B2 && $B1 || $A;           # If $Z needs to be true or false.
my $Z = $C2 && $C1 || $B2 && $B1 || $A ? 1 : 0;   # If $Z needs to be 0 or 1 specifically.
```